# a way to change the privacy of facebook post on a global or filtered

Tags: facebook, algorithm

I was thinking of a way to change the privacy of multiple posts on facebook automatically.
Can anyone tell me something?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that you can do using any of the Facebook APIs.

Comment: avoiding the api how could i do?

Comment: You can change them yourself manually for posts on your own timeline.